# Expected response in Apache Shiro when auth fails?

Tags: authentication, shiro, bearer-token

I have implemented bearer token authentication (Authentication in each request with a client-id and access-token in the header).

When I use the wrong credentials (Access-Token), I get back a "200 OK" with empty body, is this expected? Shouldn't it be a 401 or 404? When I use correct credentials I get back "200 OK" expected Json response, with body content.

I'm using the DefaultPasswordService and AuthorizingRealm. Maybe I miss something?

Using Shiro 1.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.

Before my onAccessDenied() looked like this:

```
@Override 
protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {       
    if (hasAuthorizationToken(request)) { 
        // Proceed with authentication 
        return executeLogin(request, response);           
    } 
    // Return 401 if authentication failed 
          WebUtils.toHttp(response).sendError( 
                Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode(), 
                "Oops, Authentication required"); 
    return false; 
}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
@Override  
protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) 
            throws Exception { 
        boolean authenticated = false; 
        if (hasAuthorizationToken(request)) { 
            // Proceed with authentication 
            authenticated = executeLogin(request, response);           
        } 
        // Return 401 if authentication failed 
        if (!authenticated) 
            WebUtils.toHttp(response).sendError( 
                    Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode(), 
                    "Oops, Authentication required"); 
        return authenticated;  
}
```

I needed to manually return Status.UNAUTHORIZED when authentication failed.